# How can I parse this long atributive sentence:

Tags: meaning, parsing

I have this paragraph:

> ２０１６年度東京スポーツ新聞社制定プロレス大賞技能賞に輝いた新日本プロレスのケニー・オメガ（３３）が８日、深刻な“燃え尽き症候群”に陥り、悩める胸中を明かした。

I know that "２０１６年度東京スポーツ新聞社制定プロレス大賞技能賞に輝いた新日本プロレスの" is modifying ケニー・オメガ but I'm not sure how to parse it since I don't know how 制定 fits here. The only thing I know is that ケニー・オメガ was the recipient of the ２０１６年度東京スポーツプロレス大賞技能賞 but he didn't attend the awards because of depression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following parsing:

> ２０１６年度 [[[東京スポーツ新聞社][**が**制定**した**]][プロレス大賞技能賞に輝いた]][新日本プロレスのケニー・オメガ（３３）]が[８日、深刻な“燃え尽き症候群”に陥り、悩める胸中を明かした。]

I emphasized what has been omitted. You could translate literally the whole as

> Kenny Omega (33 y.o.) who shone at the pro-race great prize, which was established by the Tokyo Sports Newspaper Agency, revealed on the eighth of this month that he has been really depressed, and expressed his troubles.

The translation is very far from perfect but it should be enough to give you an idea.

Comment: Is it normal to omit some particles or verbs in news articles? I know that they do it for headlines and sometimes the introductory part but I don't know if they do it for the article itself too

Comment: @Jon If the meaning can "easily" be reconstructed particles may be dropped. I do not read much news so I can't tell you whether this is often or not. But I would not be surprised to hear that it is common.